# For /f delims: ignore second occurance of delim-character in a line

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am using for /f to set variables in a batch file from a txt-file:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%V IN (conf.txt) DO set %%V=%%W
```

Unfortunately the string after the delim might again contain one or more times the delim character. E.g. the contents of the textfile might look like this:

```
_uploadfile=/file=upload.zip 
_password=/passphrase=ab1=cd2:def
```

Right now all text after the second occurance of the delim is not passed. So the variables when running my batch contain only

```
_uploadfile=/file
_password=/passphrase
```

Is there any option to make *for* ignoring the second occurance of the delim? Or is there a workaround? 
Chosing another character as delim seems to be no good idea as virtually all printable characters can and should be used as password.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tokens=1,*` instead.

The `*` takes in the second parameter all remaining characters from the line.
This is explained in `for /?`

Answer (score 1):

[jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39614901) is fine, unless there appear consecutive delimiters in the string, because such are treated as a single one by `for /F`. For instance, supposing `conf.txt` contains the following string...:

> ```
> str==abc
> ```

..., the command line...:

```
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%V IN (conf.txt) do set "%%V=%%W"
```

...would return this...:

> ```
> str=abc
> ```

..., so the second `=` sign is lost.

To fix the code to not fail in such situations, simply disable the delimiters at all...:

```
for /F "delims=" %%V IN (conf.txt) do set "%%V"
```

..., so the output was...:

> ```
> str==abc
> ```

..., meaning that variable `str` was set to value `=abc`.

To ensure that only lines are processed that contain at least one `=` sign, use this code:

```
for /F "delims=" %%V IN ('find "=" ^< conf.txt') do set "%%V"
```